# Adding Headers to a Multiplication Table using for-loops

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, product

I am making a product table that the user gives an input to determine its size.

The columns are labeled A-Z
The rows are labeled by Numbers with a "|" next to it.

The program prints all headers correctly. The only issue is, the product table is printed the same amount of times as the input along the rows.

See attached image for my attempt with an input of '3'.
The black product table on the image with an input of '4' is how the answer should be formatted.

```
def get_pro_tab():
        n = int(input('Please enter a positive integer: '))
        print("(Don't go too crazy)")
        print()

        #letters
        print('  ',end='')
        for letter in range(n):
                print('{0:4}'.format(chr(65 + letter)),end=' ')
        print()
        #margins
        marigin = 0
        for number in range(1, n+1):
                print(str(number)+ "|", end='')
        #numbers
                prod = 0
                for y in range(1, n+1):
                        for z in range(1, n+1):
                                prod = y * z
                                print('{0:4}'.format(str(prod)), end=' ')
                        print('\n')
```

[Attempted output and answer if the input was 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcNOJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just had one extra loop in your code. I just commented it out, now I think it works:

```
def get_pro_tab():
    n = int(input('Please enter a positive integer: '))
    print("(Don't go too crazy)")
    print()

    #letters
    print('  ',end='')
    for letter in range(n):
        print('{0:4}'.format(chr(65 + letter)),end=' ')
    print()
    #margins
    marigin = 0
    for number in range(1, n+1):
        print(str(number)+ "|", end='')
    #numbers
        prod = 0
        #for y in range(1, n+1):
        for z in range(1, n+1):
            prod = number * z
            print('{0:4}'.format(str(prod)), end=' ')
        print()
```

For input 5 this prints:

```
  A    B    C    D    E    
1|1    2    3    4    5    
2|2    4    6    8    10   
3|3    6    9    12   15   
4|4    8    12   16   20   
5|5    10   15   20   25
```

If you like, you can make your life even a bit easier by using the format strings like:

```
def get_pro_tab():
    n = int(input('Please enter a positive integer: '))
    print("(Don't go too crazy)")
    print()

    #letters
    print('  ',end='')
    for letter in range(n):
        print('{0:>4s}'.format(chr(65 + letter)),end=' ')
    print()
    #margins
    marigin = 0
    for number in range(1, n+1):
        print(str(number)+ "|", end='')
    #numbers
        prod = 0
        #for y in range(1, n+1):
        for z in range(1, n+1):
            prod = number * z
            print('{0:4d}'.format(prod), end=' ')
        print()
```

If you run this, with the same input, you get:

```
     A    B    C    D    E 
1|   1    2    3    4    5 
2|   2    4    6    8   10 
3|   3    6    9   12   15 
4|   4    8   12   16   20 
5|   5   10   15   20   25
```

Ok, I know, beauty lies in the eye of the beholder, but to me it looks more appealing if the numbers are aligned to the right. But again it was just a very small modification of your code.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I would and did add it, but can't keep it. My teacher didn't have right-aligned text in the example output pdf and I don't want points taken off for some BS reason.

Comment: It truly is beautiful, I appreciate the extra touch you added <3